# Use iptable do redirect all the HTTP traffic to localhost

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, router, wlan

I use a Linux machine as WLAN Router with the help of `hostapd` and `udhcpd`.
There's also an Apache web server installed on the same machine.

Now I want to redirect all the traffic which comes through port 80 from wlan0 to the the Apache webserver.

```
iptables -t mangle -N internet
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j internet
iptables -t mangle -A internet -j MARK --set-mark 99
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m mark --mark 99 -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1
```

This was the solution I've found. I've adjusted the IP and the interface, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there packets being matched by the mangle and NAT rules when you generate the required traffic? `sudo iptables -t mangle -L -v` `sudo iptables -t nat -L -v`

Comment: Normally you'd use `-j REDIRECT` here, I think (but both should work). Also you have a lot of extra complexity—what is with the mark? Have you actually tested with this minimal example?

Comment: It actually works if I try to connect via browser to an IP which isn't in the same network (192.168.10.10/24). But when I try to connect to something like "google.com" or "192.168.0.10" it doesn't work... Could somebody help me please?

Comment: I have the same need and I haven't been able to find anything about this subject on the www. I have hostapd running and serving ipaddresses over the WiFi but I need to connect to local host.